# PHP : Declare function signatures in the classes' headings?

Tags: php, class, method-signature

**For Best Practices** - In PHP 5.3+, can we, as for C++, declare function signares and put the bodies in the bottom of it ? If yes, how to make it ?

Example :

```
<?php
class TheDoor
{
    public $args; // [...]
    private $fields; // [...]

    public function close();
    public function open();
    [...]
    public function close()
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Thank you by advance.

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The closest you can get, as far as I know, is declaring an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) for the class to implement.

Comment: ...or an abstract class ? This would somehow correspond to headers in C/C++.